# How to repack multiple knapsacks which were at maximum capacity, had their items dumped onto a pile, shuffled, and had some items removed?

Tags: knapsack-problem, subset-sum

In this variant of the Multiple Knapsack Problem, only the weight of the items is considered, so I guess it's more like a Multiple Subset Sum Problem, but it's easier to explain with knapsacks.

There are `n` knapsacks, each filled with items to its individual maximum weight capacity `C[j]`, where `0 <= j < n`.

The knapsacks are emptied onto a pile, with a total of `m` items, each with a weight `W[i]`, where `0 <= i < m`. The items in the pile are shuffled and `k` items are removed from the pile, where `0 <= k <= m`.

`n`, `m`, `C[j]` and `W[i]` are integers larger than zero; `i`, `j` and `k` are non-negative integers.

This state is the initial input to the packing algorithm.

How to repack **all** the remaining `m - k` items so that the individual capacity of each knapsack `C[j]` is not exceeded?

- The packer has no knowledge of how the knapsacks were previously packed
- Knapsacks were previously packed, so **there exists** a valid solution
- The number of knapsacks used does not need to be optimised, there can be empty knapsacks and/or under-packed ones as well
- Items cannot be broken down into lighter pieces, even if the resulting weights are integers as well
- Items and knapsacks can be sorted if necessary
- My biggest concern is correctness, and time is more important that memory usage
- From the sample inputs I've been provided, usually `m <= 10`and `k ~= 7`, but there are cases where `m = 20`, or `k = 0` or `k = m`

I don't know if *first-fit* or *full-bin packing* algorithms are guaranteed to reach a correct result when `k` approaches zero, for example: if an algorithm packs as many small items as possible in a large knapsack, but then a large item needs to be packed and the only large knapsack is already full.

Here's an simple example in Javascript of what I want to accomplish:

```js
let knapsacks = [
  { capacity: 13 },
  { capacity: 9 },
  { capacity: 60 },
  { capacity: 81 }
];

let items = [ 52, 81, 13 ];

// all items packed
let aSolution = [
  {
    capacity: 13,
    items: [ 13 ]
  },
  { capacity: 9 },
  {
    capacity: 65,
    items: [ 52 ]
  },
  {
    capacity: 81,
    items: [ 81 ]
  }
];

// item 81 not packed
let notASolution = [
  { capacity: 13 },
  { capacity: 9 },
  { capacity: 65 },
  {
    capacity: 81,
    items: [ 52, 13 ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it known what items were removed from the packing list?  And, is it known what algorithm successfully packed the original list?  If those are known, then packing of the subset list reverts to the problem of packing the original list: Pack the original list using the previously successful packing algorithm, then remove the items from the packed knapsacks to obtain a packing of the subset list.

Comment: No, there is no knowledge of which items were removed from the packing list, and there is no knowledge of what algorithm packed the original list. The packing algorithm walks into a room and finds empty knapsacks and a pile of items. The only knowledge it has is that those items for sure were previously packed in those knapsacks.

Comment: Doesn't that turn into the base packing problem?  My understanding of knapsack type problems is that knowing there is a solution doesn't help you to find a solution.  Has it been presented that knowing there was a successful packing should help in finding a successful packing?